# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () in when deployed to vercel next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am using next js and i added `getServerSideProps` to my project and when i redeployed my project to vercel i am getting  the flowing error but my localhost is woeking perfectly

[image]

i am using next js and i added `getServerSideProps` to my project and when i redeployed my project to vercel i am getting  the flowing error but my localhost is woeking perfectly

[image]

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi`);
  const data = await res.json();
  // console.log(data);
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } };
}
```

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: if the code i provided is not enough https://github.com/vivekkn91/wixten.git here is the git repository  note that the webiste has no issue in localhost

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of an async call not completing before the next line of code that uses that variable runs. This can happen randomly because that is the nature of async code. The fix is to replace the line where you have `data.map(...)` with `data ? data.map(...) : [];` which will return an epty array until data gets its value, then the map function will run and your app should be ok.

In javascript, pretty much any time you're using a variable that is the result of an awaited activity, you should have null checks in place. The code above checks if `data` has value, then if it does have value, it will run return `data.map`, otherwise it will return `[]`.